# How to implement url page redirection for a massive huge website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

my site e.g. carparts.co.uk has 355000 unique urls. (it is a car parts catalogue site) (on webmaster tools it shows that 174000 of these are indexed)

We want to move our site to a new shopping cart platform (prestashop), and have completely changed the structure of the catalogue, which means we now have a new set of urls. (although the main domain is unchanged and is still carparts.co.uk)
i now have a excel sheet where I have a column of the 355000 'old' urls matched against the closest equivalent url on the new catalogue.
e.g.

```
old url: "carparts.co.uk/ford-ranger-alternator belts.htm"
goes to: "carparts.co.uk/belt-drive"
```

(and there are 355,000 of similar redirects)

my question is how should i do this?
i've that you can use htaccess to do this, but i'm worried because i've read that htaccess slows down sites if it is very large (is this slowness only encounted when trying to access one of the old urls?, or will it impact the speed of all my urls?

so what is the best thing for me to do with such a large number of urls?

Comment: `will it impact the speed of all my urls?` Yes, using .htaccess will slowdown the entire site, because it has to read .htaccess files on every page request. If you access to the server config, it would be best to place them in there and that will reduce that performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably setting up a RewriteMap. This requires server vhost config access as you can't configure the map from an htaccess file (though you can use one). The mapping is cached by apache so you don't need to worry about constant file access.

Something simple like:

```
RewriteMap redirects txt:/full/path/to/redirect-map.txt
```

Then in the file `redirect-map.txt` would simply have a "from" and "to":

```
"ford-ranger-alternator belts.htm" belt-drive
old-url.htm new-url
etc...
```

Then in either your htaccess file or in vhost config, just do:

```
RewriteCond $(redirects:$1|0) !=0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $(redirects:$1) [L,R]
```

Comment: Good solution, but I'd still recommend the config vs .htaccess if OP has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use of htaccess slows down the website because it needs to check several files for each request, and these are checked dynamically for every request.

It's more a problem for deep routed sites. For example, a request to:

```
www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/index.htm
```

would need to check

- The main config file.
- Then add any overrides in the document root
  htaccess file.
- Then add any overrides in the folder1 htaccess file.
- Then add any overrides in the folder2 htaccess file.

...etc.

However if you don't have deep nesting then it's not so bad. Still slower than not using them, but may not be noticeable on most sites.

The benefit of htaccess for you here, would mean that you wouldn't need to put all the redirects in one place, and could split them up amongst the htaccess file. I'm not sure of the impact of adding 355,000 redirects to the main Apache config, but it is a fair number, so imagine it could have a performance impact. The htaccess files, on the other hand, are read dynamically as the request is made, so all the redirects would not need to be loaded into Apache.

So, this might be one of the few use cases where htaccess might be a better solution, even if you do have access to the main config files.